# Is it possible to programatically add an event to my own Office 365 calendar without an Azure subscription?

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365

According to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#usernamepassword-provider) there are a jillion ways to integrate, some of which are beyond my understanding, but they seem to require a Client Id which is created via portal.azure.com

When I log into that site, it says I don't have a subscription. I don't really want an azure subscription - I have an office 365 subscription already.

Is there a way to integrate with office 365 without an azure subscription or some way that means I don't have to pay for Azure?

I have a program that runs as a windows service that books something, and when it's completed I simply wanted to insert the booking automatically into my outlook calendar.

Answer (score 0):

To access Graph API you need to give a set of permissions to your app for selected endpoints and it can be done only in Azure portal.

Comment: Does the app have to be hosted in azure too?

Comment: The app must be registered in Azure. The app itself can be run locally, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate how on earth I do that as it looks like it might be included for free with azure although it's really unclear exactly what I'm registering and how

Answer (score 0):

Every Office 365 tenant has an Azure Active Directory.

To find it go into the Office 365 Administration dashboard, click the "Show All" menu down the left and side of the page, then click "Azure Active Directory".  This will take you into the AAD admin pages in the Azure Portal.

From there you can register an application.